# CSS of my website is not loading in my wifi network, but it's working perfectly in my mobile data

Tags: html, css, web, networking

I designed a website using tailwindcss and I've used CDN. The CSS of this particular website is not loading whenever I try to access my website using my wifi network. But the website is loading perfectly when I'm connected to my mobile data. I don't what's going on here.

My website is `www.aavanto.com`

Pic of my website when I'm connected to my wifi network

[image: wifi network]

Pic of my website when I am connected to my mobile data.

[image: mobile data]

I have checked my whether are there any IPs blacklisted. So no ip addresses are blacklisted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue but it is loading fine for me. Loaded in both Chrome and Safari fine. I've not used a cdn in a while as I always import the Tailwind library into my project, but if it is still breaking on your home WIFI try doing these steps:

1. Clear your browser cache and try accessing the website again. Sometimes cached files can cause issues with loading the latest version of a website.
2. Check if other websites using the same CDN are loading correctly on your wifi network. This can help you determine if the issue is with your network or with the CDN itself.
3. If other websites using the same CDN are also not loading on your wifi network, try contacting your internet service provider to see if they are blocking the CDN. They may be able to help you resolve the issue.
4. If you have access to the router settings, try disabling any content filtering or firewall settings that may be blocking the CDN.
5. If none of the above steps work, try using a different CDN or hosting the CSS locally on your website to see if that resolves the issue.